# Call functions via HTTP requests | Trigger a function with an HTTP request | Limitations

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I really have hard time to build my app because of cloud function documentation (usage and limitations). I don't understand

I have a question,
In my app, I don't want to allow direct client-side read requests to firestore database. (client-side -> firestore database with security rules)

```
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow read: if false;
  allow write: if false;
}
```

But, I have to allow requests from client-side user through invocating a http async request or on call request. (end-user -> cloud-functions -> firestore database)

question is, Does cloud function manage scalability and load balancing techniques facing lot of traffics(100k user read requests) at a same time via http async request or app onCall request?

Example, what if 100k user request to getusers in same time?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const usersCollection = admin.firestore().collection('users');

    // Query for online male users with limit 5
    const querySnapshot = await usersCollection
      .where('isOnline', '==', 'online')
      .where('gender', '==', 'male')
      .orderBy('last-active', 'desc')
      .limit(5)
      .get();

    const userList = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const user = doc.data();
      userList.push(user);
    });

    res.status(200).json(userList);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving users:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error occurred');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does cloud function manage scalability and load balancing techniques facing lot of traffics(100k user read requests) at a same time via http async request or app onCall request?

Yes, it will scale up as needed to handle the requests as needed.

You should review the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment) to understand its behavior:

> Cloud Functions implements the serverless paradigm, in which you run your code without worrying about the underlying infrastructure, such as servers or virtual machines. Once deployed, your functions are automatically managed and scaled.
>
> Cloud Functions handles incoming requests by assigning them to instances of your function. Depending on the volume of requests, as well as the number of existing function instances, Cloud Functions may assign a request to an existing instance or create a new one.
>
> In cases where inbound request volume exceeds the number of existing instances, Cloud Functions may start multiple new instances to handle requests. This automatic scaling behavior allows Cloud Functions to handle many requests in parallel, each using a different instance of your function.

You do not get an absolute performance guarantee, but you do get this scaling behavior at no extra cost.

Comment: Thank you DOUD STEVENSON! Thanks for your effort to describe and answer me ;)

Simply, I just want know about, should I use http or onCall cloud function for maximum of 100k user requests in same time without worry like above mentioned getUsers function query? 

Can you please anwser in simple words?

Comment: It doesn't matter. They cost the same and generally behave the same.

Comment: U mean I can implement getusers functions without worry about limitations, scalability and maximum Concurrent traffic of 100k requests. Please don't mind me, you can answer simply yes or no.

Comment: I can not personally give you any guarantees because I cannot predict the real behavior of your code in GCP.  No one can.  I can only state what the documentation says, and say that you are likely within limits.  If you are experiencing problems with the product that don't match the expectations set from the documentation, you should reach out to GCP customer support.  If you want more details on quotas and limits for Cloud Functions, see here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Comment: Mr. Doug Stevenson, you don't need to predict the real behaviour of your code just use the code as a reference in above mentioned question. In the above code, what I use to deploy cloud functions in our firestore android app. So now you can easily guess the behaviour of code and you can answer it. 
Please don't ignore me, because this is our major issue to consider using firestore and  in our app. 
Please help me.. to clarify it. Note, mentioned above code is exactly same functions I used to deploy --only functions the firebase cloud function.

Thank you for giving your valuable time.